# Resolving two out of sync branches

Tags: git

I have two branches (master, development). I've merge development into master. There were merge conflicts but I've resolve them. I then deployed master. Now I would like to go back and work on development. I try:

```
git checkout development
git rebase master
```

I get merge conflicts. Given that I just resolved the merge from dev -> master, it seems to me that I shouldn't need to now resolve the same conflicts from master -> dev. How can I update my development branch so that is up to date with master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have **not done any work on development** since the merge, your branches now look like this:

```
A - B - C - D - H (master)
  \           /
    E - F - G (development)
```

To repoint `development` to `master`, you can do:

```
git checkout development
git reset --hard master
```

This:

- Checks out the development branch
- Repoints it at the same commit as master

If you **have done work on development** since the merge, your branches look like:

```
A - B - C - D - H (master)
  \           /
    E - F - G  - I - J(development)
```

In this case, you would do:

```
git checkout development
git rebase --onto master HEAD~<number of commits you care about on development>
```

This:

- Checks out the development branch
- Explicitly defines the commit that you want to rebase onto and the commits you want to move.

In that particular example, if you wanted to rebase `I` and `J` onto master, you would specify HEAD~2 for the final parameter on the rebase.